# the query with start and end date

Tags: t-sql

Can somebody help me for a query. I have the table dbo.table. I has writtenthis query:

```
select Name, Service, number, Dates, Country, Price
from dbo.table
where country is not NULL and Service in ('Incoming', 'Outgoing') and years =2014 and months=3
```

I am getting the results:

```
User1   Incoming    1111    03.07.2014  Belarus  5,5
User1   Incoming    1111    03.09.2014  Belarus  1,5
User1   Incoming    1111    03.10.2014  Belarus  1,5
User1   Outgoing    1111    03.10.2014  Belarus  2
User1   Outgoing    1111    03.11.2014  Belarus  3
User1   Outgoing    1111    03.11.2014  Belarus  4
User1   Incoming    1111    03.07.2014  France   4,3
User1   Incoming    1111    03.07.2014  France   2,7
User1   Incoming    1111    03.08.2014  France   1
User1   Outgoing    1111    03.15.2014  France   2
User1   Outgoing    1111    03.15.2014  France   3
User1   Outgoing    1111    03.15.2014  France   6
```

What should I use the query that if want get this result:

```
User1   Incoming    03.07.2014  03.10.2014  Belarus 8,5
User1   Outgoing    03.10.2014  03.11.2014  Belarus 9
User1   Incoming    03.07.2014  03.08.2014  France  8
User1   Outgoing    03.15.2014  03.15.2014  France  11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Name, Service,  MIN(Dates) as MinDate, MAX(Dates) as MaxDate, Country, SUM(Price) as Price
from dbo.table
where country is not NULL and Service in ('Incoming', 'Outgoing') and years =2014 and months=3
GROUP BY Name, Service, Country
```

Comment: If it worked, then mark it as answered so other people looking for similar answers can use this :)